# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'. In Merge statement SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge

I have a table test with 1 column as data type as ntext.

i am writing below query:

```
when matched and TARGET.Module_ID<>SOURCE.Module_ID

THEN 
UPDATE SET TARGET.Module_ID=SOURCE.Module_ID
```

But it is giving me an error

```
The data types ntext and ntext are incompatible in the not equal to operator.
```

Then I changed my query to

```
when matched and TARGET.convert(varchar(max),Module_ID) <> SOURCE.convert(varchar(max),Module_ID)
```

It is giving me an error

```
   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'.
```

What is wrong in the query?

Comment: Seems like your table design is inconsistent. Change column data type, and the error will be gone! If you have to do convert/cast to join, you're on thin ice.

Comment: `CONVERT` is a reserved keyword. You must escape it `[CONVERT]`

Comment: `TARGET.Convert`? The correct syntax for `CONVERT` is `CONVERT([datatype], [source column])`. There is no prior keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation for [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)?
You use it like this:

```
convert(varchar(max), TARGET.Module_ID) <> convert(varchar(max), SOURCE.Module_ID)
```

So your statement would be:

```
WHEN matched and convert(varchar(max), TARGET.Module_ID) <> convert(varchar(max), SOURCE.Module_ID)    
THEN 
UPDATE SET TARGET.Module_ID=SOURCE.Module_ID
```

Also a word of [warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql):

> IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a
>   future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: When I am doing convert(varchar(max),TARGET.Module_ID) = convert(varchar(max),SOURCE.Module_ID) It is still giving me an error

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your complete code?

Comment: You answere for not equal '<>' is fine only for equals '=' its not working

Comment: So? Does it solve your problem? The equal operator doesn't make much sense in this context as far as I can see from your code fragment.

Comment: If you check the syntax for merge first we have to check if its not equal then we have to update. So your query for conversion is not working for update

Comment: Ah, now I get what you mean. You mean the equality in the update itself! In that case you don't need to convert at all! Please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use CAST function.

```
when matched and CAST(TARGET.Module_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) <> CAST(SOURCE.Module_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

You can read more from here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql